# How to compare two .csv files?

Tags: java, string, csv, try-catch

```
 /**
 * 5 points
 *
 * Return the price of the stock at the given date as a double. Each line
 * of the file contains 3 comma separated
 * values "date,price,volume" in the format "2016-03-23,106.129997,25703500" 
 * where the data is YYYY-MM-DD, the price
 * is given in USD and the volume is the number of shares traded throughout 
 * the day.
 *
 * Note: You don't have to interpret dates for this assignment and you can use 
 * the Sting's .equals method to 
 * compare dates whenever date comparisons are needed.
 * 
 * @param stockFileName The filename containing the prices for a stock for each 
 *                      day in 2016
 * @param date          The date to lookup given in YYYY-MM-DD format
 * @return The price of the stock represented in stockFileName on the given date
 */
public static double  getPrice(String stockFileName, String date) {
  try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(stockFileName));
    String line = "";
    String unparsedFile = "";
    Double Price;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
      String[] Ans = unparsedFile.split(",");
      for (String item : Ans){ 
        if(Ans[1].equals(date)){
          double aDouble = Double.parseDouble(Ans[2]);    
          return aDouble;
        }
      }
    }
    br.close();

  } catch (IOException ex) {
    System.out.println("Error"); 
  }
  return Ans;
}
```

The code I have now will I assume compare only one column of the .csv file to the date parameter. How do I make it so that code will look for an individual line then compare [1] of that line to the date parameter and return [2] of that line back?

Comment: Can we get more explanation in word?

Answer (score 0):

I think that your code is close to being (functionally) correct.  The mistake that you have made is that Java arrays are indexed from zero, not from one.  So `Ans[1]` is actually giving you the second element of the array ... not the first one.

Solution: obvious ... assuming that you understand what I just wrote above!

Once you have fixed the bug(s), you should fix the style issues:

- Always start the names of variables with a lower case letter.
- Use 4 spaces as your indentation level
- One space after `if`.
- One space between `)` and `{`